# Issues with Ng-Options with JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

My JSON has Accounts, Contacts, and Ticket information within it. It will output the `Account` and `Contact` as a dropdown using ng-repeat to give the user their options. This works perfectly, until either `Account` or `Contact` have only one value.

HTML

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" 
    id="accountSelect" ng-model="option.account" 
    ng-options="account.id as account.name for account in accounts | orderBy: 'name'">
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
$scope.accounts = info.Account.Account;
```

Example of JSON (simplified)

```
{  
   "Account":{  
      "Account":{  
         "id":1234567,
         "name":"Account Name",
         "phone":"123-456-7890"
      },
      "count":1
   },
   "Contacts":{  
      "Contacts":[  
         {  
            "id":1234,
            "name":"Smith, John",
            "accountID":1234567
         },
         {  
            "id":56789,
            "name":"Smith, Jane",
            "accountID":1234567
         }
      ],
      "count":2
   }
}
```

For me, the `select` options are all populated by `undefined` values. If there are more than one `Account`, this works fine. Why is that?

Comment: try this orderBy: 'account.name'"

Comment: That didn't fix the issue unfortunately. All the options are still `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Account.Account` is an object not `array`.

your account should be an `array`.

Like:

```
"Account":{  
      "Account":[{  
         "id":1234567,
         "name":"Account Name",
         "phone":"123-456-7890"
      }],
      "count":1
   }
```

Comment: Perfect! Some adjustments made to my PHP file that creates the JSON data to account for this, and it works like a charm. Thank you very much.